# Firebase Storage Multiple photo Upload Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload multiple photos to my Firebase Storage. For some reason it keeps overwriting the original upload, and it's not creating the folder with the `venueID` property. Can anybody shine a light here?

**main.ts**

```
async localPictureUpload(): Promise<any> {
    // Checks if there is something to be uploaded.
    if (this.photosToUpload.length > 0) {
        const location = `venues/photos/${this.venueID}/`;
        // photosToUpload is an array containing base64 strings.
        this.photosToUpload.forEach(async photoElement => {
            const randomID = this.venueService.createID();
            await this.uploadService.uploadFile(photoElement, location, true)
                .then(async data => {
                    const urlData = await data.ref.getDownloadURL();
                    const photoObject: Photo = {
                        fileName: `${this.venueID}${randomID}`,
                        url: urlData,
                        uploadedBy: this.currentUserID
                    };
                    await this.venueService.addPhoto(this.venueID, photoObject);
                },
                (err) => console.error(err));
        });
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

**upload.service**

```
uploadFile(file: any, path: string, base64?: boolean) {
    if (base64) {
        return this.uploadDB.ref(path).putString(file, 'data_url');
    } else {
        return this.uploadDB.upload(path, file);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance the code for setting the path looks fine. Can you try: 1) Adding `console.log(path);` right before `this.uploadDB.ref(path).putString(file, 'data_url')` and showing the output? 2) Replacing the complex code with a simpler hard-coded path with `/` in it, to see if that works. After doing these, please edit your question to show the updated (hopefully simpler) result and output.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen this is what I get on the path console.log `venues/photos/0WiFtVRvPj63GlEAqsEF/` that seems ok right? In theory the last part should be the folder (which has the record id) and the file should be added right after, correct?

Comment: Does my answer helped ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all the pictures share the same location inside the firesotrage bucket. Because you setup the location path before the forEach.

This code below should create venues/photos/venueID/yourPictures

```
  // Checks if there is something to be uploaded.
  if (this.photosToUpload.length > 0) {
    // photosToUpload is an array containing base64 strings.
    this.photosToUpload.forEach(async photoElement => {
      const randomID = this.venueService.createID();
      const location = `venues/photos/${this.venueID}/${randomID}/`;
      // const location = `venues/photos/${this.venueID}/`; <---- The problem 
      //  const randomID = this.venueService.createID(); 
      await this.uploadService.uploadFile(photoElement, location, true)
        .then(async data => {
            const urlData = await data.ref.getDownloadURL();
            const photoObject: Photo = {
              fileName: `${this.venueID}${randomID}`,
              url: urlData,
              uploadedBy: this.currentUserID
            };
            await this.venueService.addPhoto(this.venueID, photoObject);
          },
          (err) => console.error(err));
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but the problem is that I need to generate a random id for each picture that's being uploaded. If I leave it outside the `foreach` it will repeat that value for every record.